# Count certain record in database

Tags: asp-classic

How can I count the number of certain records in database using classic asp? For example, I want to count how many record are there for Car..I'm using ms access. need help. thank you.

Comment: You may want to see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057175/how-to-count-records-in-asp-classic

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE Field = 'Car'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `car` a table?

```
select count(1) from car
```

Just like any other query.