# "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed" when executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

This is my stored procedure, and when I am calling it from my classic ASP code, I am getting the error:

> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

when I try to do a record count.

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

I am trying to return the table `@t`.

Thanks.

```
USE [Hires_new]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_selectNewHireWorkPeriodsSQL]    Script Date: 05/13/2013 14:04:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      
-- Create date: 
-- Description: 
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_selectNewHireWorkPeriodsSQL] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS

    declare @t table (HireID int, StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime, date_initiated datetime, date_closed datetime, firmName nvarchar(100), InquiryID int)
    DECLARE @acc INT 
    SET @acc = 1
    DECLARE @max INT 
    select @max = max(HireID) from NewHire
    WHILE (@acc <= @max)
        BEGIN
            IF (@acc in (select HireID from NewHire))
                BEGIN
                    insert into @t  
                        select HireID, StartDate, EndDate, date_initiated, date_closed, firmName, Inquiries.InquiryID 
                        from WorkPeriod, Firms, Inquiries 
                        where HireID = @acc and WorkPeriod.FirmID = Firms.FirmID and WorkPeriod.InquiryID = Inquiries.InquiryID 
                        order by HireID,StartDate DESC
                END
            set @acc = @acc + 1
        END
    select * from @t
```

Asp classic code

```
selectNewHireWorkPeriodsSQL = "EXEC sp_selectNewHireWorkPeriodsSQL"
Set rsNewHireWorkPeriods = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsNewHireWorkPeriods.Open selectNewHireWorkPeriodsSQL,ConnectionString,adOpenStatic
NumOfNewHireWorkPeriods = rsNewHireWorkPeriods.RecordCount

response.write(NumOfNewHireWorkPeriods)
```

Comment: I mean the microsoft sql server.

Comment: Since the error obviously is in the calling code - you need to show us the code **calling** this stored procedure ....

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: ok I posted it. The error comes from when I  try to do a record count.

Comment: As another side note, there seems to be no need for a loop in this code: you could write the whole thing as a single `SELECT` statement by adding a join on `NewHire`. And it would be best to [write your joins explicitly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins).

Comment: How would you re write it?

Answer (score 77):

Try this in your stored procedure:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
```

Right below the `AS`.

Comment: set nocount on did it for us

Comment: This fixed a problem I had getting a result set from a procedure using BarTender software for printing labels. (I had the same error)

Comment: Great! Worked smoothly!

Comment: It also works outside the stored procedure, if you're in a situation where you can't modify it. Just add them before the EXEC call in your query.

Comment: Worked for me. Is there any chance anyone could provide an explanation?

Comment: SET NOCOUNT on prevents SQL server from returning the "x records affected" output when your queries contain updates or inserts. I can't remember the exact reason, but ADO gets confused when there's text output from a query. (I think it misinterprets it as an error message and aborts.)

Comment: FWIW, I did not need to 'set ansi warnings off'. Also, I found that the behavior was not consistent. Sometimes things worked without 'set nocount on' and sometimes they did not. However, using 'set nocount on' everywhere did fix things nicely.

Answer (score 4):

If, for whatever reason the stored procedure does not return a result set, empty or otherwise, the recordset object will not be open, so:

```
if rs.state = adStateOpen then x = rs.recordcount
```

Comment: The results of testing on my end disagrees with this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an active connection first, and pass this to the recordset object, like this:

```
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open(ConnectionString)

selectNewHireWorkPeriodsSQL = "EXEC sp_selectNewHireWorkPeriodsSQL"
Set rsNewHireWorkPeriods = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsNewHireWorkPeriods.Open selectNewHireWorkPeriodsSQL,conn,adOpenStatic 'dont use connection string here
NumOfNewHireWorkPeriods = rsNewHireWorkPeriods.RecordCount

conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing

response.write(NumOfNewHireWorkPeriods)
```

Comment: I thought ADO's Recordset Open method would implicitly open a connection, if only a connection string was passed.

Comment: @G. Stoynev, just checked the documentation and it seems you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Warnings may confuse the result. `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` avoids losing the SELECT result or output parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that this will not affect many people, but I just stumbled upon this issue. This was working in production and not in the development environment. What I found was that our stored procedure had a print statement in the development environment. I guess the print statement was mucking up the works and ADODB thought that was the record set.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is very old. But in my case, **it was the order of parameters**. It worked after I set the parameters as they appear in the stored procedure. I know that there is no logical explanation to this as parameters are named and the order should not matter really.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a print statement in your stored procedure. I accidently left a few in after some performance debugging....hopefully this helps someone still working in legacy ADO.