# Classic ASP-Determine if any records have been returned from a query

Tags: sql, database, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP webpage which is retrieving data from a database and displaying it in an HTML table.  Under some circumstances there may not be any data and I want to trap that situation and display an informational message.  Here are snippets of my code:

```
MySite = "filedsn=" & Server.MapPath("/" & WebName & "/fpdb/reffiles/accessdsn.dsn") &      ";DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("/" & WebName & "/fpdb/reffiles/my.mdb") & ";DefaultDir=" _
& Server.MapPath("/" & WebName & "/") & ";"
set MyDatabase = server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
Mydatabase.open(MySite) 

strSQLMin = "SELECT Format(Min(Date_Time),'dd/mm/yy') AS MinOfDate_Reading, Format(Min(INV_Bat), '###0.0') AS MinOfTempBat, " _
& "Format(Min(INV_tfmr), '###0.0') AS MinOfTempTransf, Format(Min(INV_FET), '###0.0') AS MinOfTempFET, " _
& "Min(BMK_soc) AS MinOfStateOfCharge, min(BMK_vdc) AS MinOfBatDCVolts, Format(Min(BMK_adc),'###0') AS MinOfBatDCAmps, " _
& "Min(INV_VACout) AS MinOfInvACVoltsOut, Min(INV_AACout) AS MinOfWInvACAmpsOut, format(Min(INV_VACin),'###0') AS MinOfInvACVoltsIn, " _
& "Format(Min(INV_AACin),'###0') AS MinOfInvACAmpsIn, Format(Min(INV_vdc),'###0') AS MinOfInvDCVolts, " _
& "Format(Min(INV_adc),'###0') AS MinOfInvDCAmps, Format(Min(INV_Hz),'###0') AS MinOfACFreq " _
& "FROM magnum2 WHERE (((tbl2.Date_Time)<Now() And (tbl2.Date_Time)>Now()-1))"

set WeekRecMin = MyDatabase.Execute(strSQLMin)
```

to check and see if any records have been returned before I create and fill the webpage table, I added this code around the table

```
<% response.write("<h2>EOF and BOF are : " & weekRecMin.eof & "  -  " & weekRecMin.bof & "</h2>") %>
<% if WeekRecMin.EOF=true then %>
...HTML code ...
<% else %>
<% response.write("<tr><td class='auto-style6'><h4>no data found for the past 24 hours. <br/> Database may be out-of-date</h4></td></tr>") %>
<% end if %>
```

What I'm observing is that both EOF and BOF are false regardless of whether or not data has been returned from the query, otherwise the page and code are working fine.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitely specifying parameters for your recordset and see if it makes any difference (I guess it will):

```
set MyDatabase = server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
set myRecordset = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Mydatabase.open(MySite) 
myRecordset.Open strSqlMin, myDatabase, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
if not myRecordset.Eof then
    ...
else
    ...
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objrs = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.RecordSet")   
objrs.Open SqlStr, DbConnect, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic,adCmdText
If Objrs.RecordCount <= 0 Then
    Response.Write "Sorry, No Records Found"
Else
    While Not Objrs.EOF
       Reponse.Write " Writing records and stuff <br>" 
    Objrs.MoveNext
    Wend
End If
Objrs.Close
Set objrs = Nothing
```

Comment: used Objrs.RecordCount <= 0 because some databases will return -1 instead of 0 if there are no records found.

Answer (score -1):

I generally go for this approach and check for NOT BOF

```vb
    Set oDB= Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")
    oDB.CursorLocation = adOpenStatic
    oDB.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;etc etc"
    sql = "SELECT etc etc etc "
    Set rs1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Call rs1.Open(sql, oDB, adOpenStatic)
    if not rs1.BOF then
        ' This means there's a recordset of results
    end if
```

Answer (score -1):

Ralpharama and ChrisBE…..I tried both of your suggestions without success.  I had to modify ChrisBE's since using

> myRecordset.Open strSqlMin, myDatabase, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

Threw an error,  I removed the adLockOptimistic since it did not seem to be appropriate to just retrieving and printing elements. After I removed it your codes worked.

Regardless, in both cases EOF and BOF were false whether or not records had been retrieved.

I found this reference ([how to count records in ASP classic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057175/how-to-count-records-in-asp-classic)) which used this type of SQL string

```
' This code checks for no data returned from the last 24 hours  
<%    strCountSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumRecs FROM table2 WHERE (((table2.Date_Time)<Now() And (table2.Date_Time)>Now()-1))"
set MinRecordset = MyDatabase.Execute(strCountSQL)
iTotalRecords = MinRecordset.Fields("NumRecs ")
MinRecordset.Close

if iTotalRecords > 0 then %>                
...html code
<% else  
response.write("<tr><td class='auto-style6'><h4>no data found for the past 24 hours. <br/> Database may be out-of-date</h4></td></tr>") %>
end if %>
```

and then setting up an if statement which looked at NumRecs to see if it was greater than 0.

For my code this worked like a charm.  Thanks for your time.....RDK